# AVFoundation to overlay two video clips with Alpha compositing in ios5?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, avfoundation, alpha, gpuimage

I'm hoping to use IOS5 AV Foundation with or without Open GL to record video from the camera and overlay/merge another video clip on top using some form of alpha channel compositing / foreground matting.

A sample use case of the combined output may be a video of an animated character interacting with the the user's recorded video clip from the iPhone/iPad camera.

Is this possible right now with IOS5 or potentially with Brad Larson's GPUImage framework? Can the alpha channels of the two video sources be combined easily?

If anyone has any sample code they could share, or offer any guidance I'd be really appreciative.

Comment: As a note, my movie playback timing is messed up right now, so it needs to be fixed in order for movie sources to be composited correctly with live video. I can do the compositing, but the movie input needs a little love.

Comment: Hi @BradLarson .. thank you for your input. Right now all I'm looking to do is a proof of concept so it doesn't need to be perfect to begin with. If you could point me to what API's of yours I could start with or some sample code would be invaluable. Thanks again.

Comment: Look at the SimpleVideoFileFilter example that ships with the framework to see how to process a video file through a filter, then check out the various blends in the FilterShowcase example. Those examples combined should show how to do what you want here.

Comment: @MarkOLeary I am trying to do exactly the same thing. Did you succeed by following Brad Larson's guidance? If so, would you be so kind to point me on the right track?

Comment: @MarkOLeary Even I'm trying to overlap two videos, where the video on top will have alpha channel. Did you succeed in doing it? If YES can you guide me.

Comment: @MarkOLeary Multiple people hoping for an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Apple [AVEditDemo](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645) (+ accompanying WWDC 2010 video) would be a start. Doesn't show video overlays w/ alpha but if you haven't worked with AVFoundation before this is an excellent intro.

Here's another good walkthrough [video-composition-with-ios](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/15/video-composition-with-ios/)

Comment: Thank you so much @skinnyTOD. I have gone through all of the WWDC2011 but I'll check out the sample you mentioned above in WWDC2010. The other walk-through is helpful but it deals more with stitching clips together and creating a type of workflow rather than video overlaying. But really appreciate your help here.

Comment: The link is broken